# My .xsession and .xinitrc files are not executing

Tags: ubuntu, session, xmonad, login-manager

I have installed xmobar, xmonad on ubuntu 11.04.

```sh
#!/bin/bash

trayer --edge top --align right --SetDockType true --SetPartialStrut true \
   --expand true --width 10 --transparent true --tint 0x191970 --height 12 &

nm-applet --sm-disable &

sleep 3
gnome-power-manager &

xmonad
```

I put this in my `.xsession` file. But it does not seem to execute. I believe so because I do not see any of the applications in my processes list after the xmonad starts. Is there anything I am missing?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think the most probable stopper here would be that your `.xsession` script lacks the execute permission (`+x`).

In `gdm`, you also need to choose “Custom Session” (and not the standard “Xmonad” session) in the *Session* menu before logging in.

Comment: This was the key for me

Answer (score -1):

Can also use `.xprofile` to execute additional programs (no +x needed btw) to xmonad.