# .xsession and .xinitrc not executed at login

Tags: ubuntu, login, session, xmonad

This is the content of my `~/.xsession`:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Tray for skype, keyboard layout, ...
trayer --edge top --align right --SetDockType true --SetPartialStrut true  --expand true --width 10 --transparent true --tint 0x686868 --height 17 &

# Keyboard layout switcher
setxkbmap -layout us,se -option 'grp:alt_shift_toggle' &

xscreensaver -nosplash &
```

After login with xmonad selected in lightdm, xscreensaver is not running, neither is trayer, and setxkbmap is not setup.

I have seen [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/21905/my-xsession-and-xinitrc-files-are-not-executing), which is exactly the same, but the answers there did not help:

- `~/.xsession` is executable for all
- I have no option "Custom session" in the login manager (Ubuntu's default)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It turns out I had created my own start script `xmonad-start.sh`, and changed `/usr/share/xsessions/xmonad.desktop`'s `Exec` line to run this script. I still quite don't get why X wouldn't run `~/.xsession` whatever the WM, but adding `~/.xsession` to my script `xmonad-start.sh` worked.

[This question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/59281/xinitrc-not-being-run) helped.

---

In my fresh installation (Ubuntu 15.10 and `xmonad` from `apt-get`), this is how it works:

- `/usr/share/xsessions/xmonad.desktop` is what is called upon login with `lightdm`
- this in turn has the row `Exec=xmonad-session`
- `xmonad-session` is in `/usr/bin`, and sources `.xmonad/xmonad-session-rc` if it exists.

So you can just create a symbolic link `~/.xmonad/xmonad-session-rc` to wherever your start script is.

No tinkering in files that are not the user's.

Comment: On Centos7, /usr/bin/xmonad-start looks for a ~/.xmonad/session file to load (among others). Moving ~/.xsession to ~/.xmonad/session (or symlinking) works.